# Запрос JPA-repository на получение записей из таблицы по списку id?

Tags: sql, jpa, repository

Приложение на  Spring + jpa + jpa Crud repository + hibernate-envers

У меня две таблицы, UserRecord и UserRecord_AUD(вторая создана автоматически хибернейтом)

```
        Table UserRecord
id   name  surname  age version

       Table UserRecord_AUD
id   name  surname  age version REV REVINFO
```

Когда я записываю пользователя в базу, он записывается в таблицу UserRecord.
Если я обновляю запись, например обновив возраст пользователя, то, новая версия записывается в UserRecord, а старая переносится в UserRecord_AUD.
Таким образов, в UserRecord_AUD накапливаются все записи(историчность) и у них одинаковое значение в поле Id.

Задача в том, чтобы прочитать записи из RiskMetric_AUD с одинаковым id используя CrudRepository от spring.

Пример:

```
===============================
    Table UserRecord
  11-1  Ivan      Ivanov  23 2
  22-2  Natasha   Ivanova 22 1
===============================
    Table UsersRecord_AUD
  11-1  Ivan      Ivanov  9  0
  11-1  Ivan      Ivanov  9  1
  22-2  Natasha   Ivanova 22 0
===============================
```

Мой репозиторий

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<UserRecord, String> 
{}
```

Мне требуется кастомный метод, принимающий список id.
И вместо последовательного вызова(когда мне нужно 10 раз запросить историю для разных id)
    repository.find(id);

Единоразовый запрос по списку id:

```
repository.find(ids);
```

Как это сделать?:

Пробовал

```
@Query(value = "select id, name, surname, age, REV as VERSION, IDCALC from USERRECORD_AUD where PR_KEY in (:ids)", nativeQuery = true)
List<UserRecord> findHistoryByIds(List<String> ids);
```

Но, получил исключение

> Name for parameter binding must not be null or empty! On JDKs < 8, you
>   need to use @Param for named parameters, on JDK 8 or better, be sure
>   to compile with -parameters.; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for parameter binding must
>   not be null or empty! On JDKs < 8, you need to use @Param for named
>   parameters, on JDK 8 or better, be sure to compile with -parameters.

Моя JPA сущность:

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name = "UserRecord")
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class UserRecord {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 100, unique = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "surname", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String surname;


    @Column(name = "age", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String age;

    @Version
    private int version;
```

Так же пробовал вариант:

```
@Query(value = "select id, name, surname, age, REV as VERSION, IDCALC from USERRECORD_AUD where PR_KEY in :ids", nativeQuery = true)
List<UserRecord> findHistoryByIds(@Param("ids") List<String> ids);
```

Но, например если была одна запись и три обновления, то есть по идее ожидалось что вернутся 4 разных сущности, вернулась одна сущность, 4 раза.

Вариант

```
@Query("select h.PR_KEY, h.name, h.surname, h.age, h.REV as VERSION from USERRECORD_AUD h where h.PR_KEY in (:ids)")
    List<UserRecord> findHistoryByIds(List<String> ids);
```

вернул ошибку маппинга

> QuerySyntaxException: USERRECORD_AUD is not mapped [select h.PR_KEY,
>   h.name, h.surname, h.age, h.REV as VERSION from USERRECORD_AUD h where
>   h.PR_KEY in (:ids)")
>           List findHistoryByIds(List ids)]